# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Session Id changes with Cybersource reply to mvc-action. Loosing Session objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cybersource

ASP.NET MVC 5 application on .NET framework 4.5.2.

Using CyberSource to submit payment.

When submitting payment sending parameter to CyberSource:
"override_custom_receipt_page" which specifies MVC Action that Cybersource should come back to after processing payment.

In the production environment, payment is sent to

```
 https://secureacceptance.cybersource.com . . . .
```

All works fine.

In local, DEV, QA environments, payment is sent to

```
 https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com . . . .
```

And in these environments CS does come back to the specified MVC action, but SessionId is different, not the SessionId of the session that sent request to CS.

And of course MVC action can't find any Session objects, needed to process reply from CS.

And reply is processed incorrectly.

I googled, found some info re changing session id, tried some recommendations, doesn't help.

Global.asax.cs does have Session_Start:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
     Session["init"] = 0;
}
```

Also, in `web.config`:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="20">    
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<..value here..>" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

DEV, QA, PROD environments are in Azure.

Also, it seems so far that code worked fine for 5 years then it broke in Local, DEV, QA.

It seems as it may have broke after DEV and QA environments have been moved to Azure.

But, Local env is not in Azure, it's my own laptop.

There is no load balancer for Local, DEV, QA.

ALSO,
I just found info on "Chrome is changed how cookies work since Dec 2019",
about sameSite attribute.

But, again - Why same code Works in Production without sameSite
and doesn't work in other environment?

If anybody may have any idea about what may be going on, why CS can't come back to the same session, it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue while working with a different payment gateway. In our case the session variable worked in DEV but didn't work in the production environment.

It is mostly because a session is attached to a thread and when payment gateway returns to the callback url of the website it was creating a new thread and loosing the session variable.

To resolve the issue we passed a reference number (in our case it was the invoice number) to the payment gateway. After successful payment, the gateway returned the reference number along with other details. We retrieved customer details from the reference number and proceeded with the next steps.

Comment: Yes, I undertand, thank you. But it's kind of work around I think. In our case some data are saved Only in Session object before payment processing and retrieved after payment processing, because those data should Not be saved if payment didn't happen. Also it worked in all environments for 5 years and still working in prod. Something with Azure environment I would think may be? Orwith Cybersource in a way how CSTest works with Azure?

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using to test locally? If it is Chrome try with a different browser and see if the issue is resolved. This would mean the issue was with the cookies, not the session.